# Sending email two multiple recipients but different body using PHP

Tags: php, html-email

I have one contact form, when user submit all value will send(email) to admin.But now i want to do when user submit admin will receive the email and user also will receive an email but with different body.

here my previous code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "admin@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Lifemailer Sales Enquiry";
$email_to_user= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    $URL = "error.html";
header("Location: $URL");
die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['contact']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email_sub']) ||
    !isset($_POST['remarks'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form your
     submitted.');      
}

$name = $_POST['name']; // not required
$contact = $_POST['contact']; // required
$email = $_POST['email']; // required
$email_sub = $_POST['email_sub']; // required
$remarks = $_POST['remarks']; // required


$error_message = "";
$string_exp = "^[a-z .'-]+$";
  if(!eregi($string_exp,$name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
 }
    $string_exp = "^[0-9 .-]+$";
  if(!eregi($string_exp,$contact)) {
$error_message .= 'The Contact Number you entered does not appear to be valid.
 <br     />';
  }
$email_exp = "^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
  if(!eregi($email_exp,$email)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.
  <br    />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
  }
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Contact Number: ".clean_string($contact)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email Subject : ".clean_string($email_sub)."\n";
$email_message .= "Remarks/Enquiry : ".clean_string($remarks)."\n";



    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
     @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
     $URL = "thank-you.html";
     header("Location: $URL");



     ?>

    Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

     <?
      }
     ?>
```

Comment: send two mails with two body

Comment: Possible duplication - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510030/how-to-do-email-form-with-multiple-recipients-and-different-body . Have a look at this question.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

In the same way you can send a second mail with different subject, email_to, email_message after sending it to admin.

Answer (score 0):

```
  just concatenate

  $email_to = ' admin@gmail.com ' . ',' ;

  $email_to  . = ' admin@gmail.com ' ;
```

Comment: FYI: Your answer won't work for what the person is asking about. Biswajit's suggestion/answer is the way to go about it.